# Strange max(date) return in reader vs writer aurora mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, datetime, aws-aurora

Something very strange happening here which I can't point out. Using AWS Aurora, select max(date) in the writer gives me one date, in the reader it returns strange date and warnings.. Column is `datetime`.

writer:

```
MySQL [(none)]> select max(colDT) from tbl_example;
+---------------------+
| max(colDT)          |
+---------------------+
| 2020-02-12 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

reader:

```
MySQL [(none)]> select id from tbl_example where colDT=(select max(colDT) from tbl_example);
Empty set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                     |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: ':082-05-31 31:63:51' for column 'colDT' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: ':082-05-31 31:63:51' for column 'colDT' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: ':082-05-31 31:63:51' for column 'colDT' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Some more strangeness:

```
MySQL [(none)]> select max(colDT),id from tbl_example ;
+---------------------+-------+
| max(colDT)          | id    |
+---------------------+-------+
| :082-05-31 31:63:51 | 94113 |
+---------------------+-------+
1 row in set (46.47 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> select * from tbl_example where id=94113;
+-------+-------+---------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| id    | bbbbb | colDT               | cc      | dd     | ee      |
+-------+-------+---------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 94113 |     1 | 2019-08-07 00:00:00 |       6 |     17 |       1 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+---------+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table definition:

```
MySQL [(none)]> show create table tbl_example\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tbl_example
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tbl_example ` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bbbbb` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `colDT` datetime NOT NULL,
  `cc` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dd` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ee` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`colDT`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ux_date_dd` (`colDT`,`dd`),
  KEY `dd` (`dd`),
  KEY `cc` (`cc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1078720 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(colDT)
(PARTITION p20190601 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20190701 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-08-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20190801 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-09-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20190901 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong in the reader, after a restart the issue went away.